# how to create a world map using highmaps and disable part of legend?

Tags: highmaps, world-map

I have created a world map using highmaps. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/zhaojun08/jnmoyzgL/2/

```
$(function () {

    // Prepare demo data
    var data = [
        {
            "hc-key": "fo",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "um",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "hc-key": "us",
            "value": 2
        }
    ];

    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

        title : {
            text : 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },

        subtitle : {
            text : 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js">World, Miller projection, high resolution</a>'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            name: 'Region',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.name}'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.name}'
            }
        },{
            type: 'mappoint',
            name: 'Cities',
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineColor: 'black',
                lineWidth: 1,
                radius: 2
            },
            data: [{
                name: 'Mountain View',
                lon: -122.07,
                lat: 37.40
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

But the legend of the map has two parts, one is the left part with dataRange, the other is right part with 'server'. I want to delete the left part and reserve the right part, for I want to create a pure map.

What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have soled this problem by using showInLegend option.